# assigning a file path to a program from terminal

Tags: c++

I'd like to assign a file path to the program from the terminal,

inside my program the code is like:

```
#include<iostream>

int main{

fstream file;
file.open("path",ios::in);
...
```

and I want to use

```
./myprogram /filepath
```

in the terminal to let my program receive the path,
how can I achieve it?

Comment: I don't know what compiler you are using, but `int main{` seems like it should not even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use command line arguments. But your main should look like as below.
Where `argc` shows the argument count (including the executable itself) and `argv` shows the arguments (including the name of the executable itself). So `argc = 1`, `argv = {"myProgram"}` by default. (if your output file is "myProgram")

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    fstream file;
    if (argc == 2){
        file.open(argv[1],ios::in);
    }else{
        // handle the error
    }
}
```

When you run the program :

```
./myProgram "/filepath"
```

But make sure to check `argc`, before using `argv[1]`, to avoid segmentation faults, when there are no additional arguments given.

Answer (score 2):

Your main function declaration should look like this:

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
```

The integer, **argc** is the argument count. It is the number of arguments passed into the program from the command line, including the name of the program.

The **array of character** pointers is the listing of all the arguments.

I'd suggest using `Boost.Program_options` to parse arguments.